# Cannot browse to web sites where server is on same router

Tags: networking, router, dns

I have a cable router which provides NAT addresses 10.1.10.X as well as has static IPs on it. My local development computer is plugged directly into the router and so is the web server.

The web server (Windows 2008) is configured with 50.253.xxx.xxx static addresses. The development computer (Windows 7) gets assigned a DHCP 10.1.xxx.xxx address.

If I browse to any of the websites hosted on the web server from some remote network (or even browsing via 4G over phone) everything works fine.

If I try to browse to any of those same sites from my development computer the browser never gets returned a response. If I do a tracert to any of the websites, it takes a single hop and resolves. There has been occasions when the browser would return the web page, but this is intermittent. Outlook can hit the mail server (on the same physical box as the web sites) and it usually works, but occasionally will fail as well.

I do not know where to start because I am not sure if this is a DNS issue or routing issue.

Comment: Well, yeah the cellphone will work fine if you are on 4G - that is connecting to an external network.   Do you have any additional computers that you could hook up to eliminate or single out the dev machine as the issue?   How about if you browse the internet from the webserver, does it resolve websites other than your website when you browse from it?   If so, open a command prompt and type ipconfig /all.   Then go to your dev machine and do the same thing and compare results.   Do the internal gateway and subnet masks match up?   What do you mean when you say "those same sites"?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. No computers on the same LAN can access pages on the web server. It can only be accessed from an external network (thus I referenced the 4G).

Comment: From the web server it resolves immediately and browses just fine. (those same sites refers to any of the sites on the web server).

Comment: Sorry keep hitting return by accident... on the dev machine I have an IP of 10.1.10.13, gateway 10.1.10.1 and subnet of 255.255.255.0 and on the web server I have 50.253.x.x, and a subnet of 255.255.255.248. What is odd is that if I browse to "What Is My IP" from my dev machine it shows the IPv6 address and the server shows a IPv4 address. If I set my dev machine to use IPv4 it does not provide the same IP as the web server. Would think that since they are both on the same router, that they would both have the same broadcast address.